# Program esp32 using Raspberry pi GPIO via Openocd

Tags: esp32, raspberry-pi4, openocd

I am using Raspberry pi 4 GPIO's to flash the firmware in ESP32 pico mini and using the below command

connection:

```
ESP32             Rpi GPIO
pin 14            pin 18(SWDIO)
pin 13            pin 22(SWCLK)
EN                pin 12(Reset)
GND               GND
```

Note: I have used the same method for nrf52 and it is working with nrf52.
Please help if anyone faced similar issue and how can I solve this error?

command: `/opt/openocd/src/openocd -f interface/rpi.cfg -c "adapter speed 1000" -f target/esp32.cfg -c "flash init; init; halt; flash erase_sector 0 1 last; exit"  -s /opt/openocd-esp32/tcl`

Response of the command:

```
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
force hard breakpoints
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : BCM2835 GPIO JTAG/SWD bitbang driver
Info : clock speed 995 kHz
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: esp32.cpu0: IR capture error; saw 0x00 not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Error: Unexpected OCD_ID = 00000000
Warn : target esp32.cpu0 examination failed
Error: Unexpected OCD_ID = 00000000
Warn : target esp32.cpu1 examination failed
Info : starting gdb server for esp32.cpu0 on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
```

Comment: Where do you get the idea that you could program an ESP32 with SWD programmer? SWD programmer is for ARM- based MCU like STM32, nerf52, etc., but I'm not aware that it can be used for programming an ESP32.